WSS using Netty
I implemented a websocket client/server using Netty. It works fine using WS (non secure), but it doesn't work using WSS. I followed this example: https://nikoskatsanos.com/blog/2022/01/netty-websocket-ssl/.
Here is the server code:
public class WebSocketServer {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketServer.class);

    private enum WebSocketProtocol {WS, WSS};
    private static final List<Channel> openChannels = new ArrayList<Channel>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        final String protocol;
        final int port;

        logger.info("Initiating server configuration");
        try {
            protocol = WebSocketProtocol.valueOf(args[0]).toString().toLowerCase();
            port = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception parsing main arguments", e);

            StringBuilder argsString = new StringBuilder().append("[");
            for (int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++) {
                argsString.append(args[i]);
                if (i < args.length - 1) {
                    argsString.append(" ");
                }
            }
            argsString.append("]");

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Excepted args: WS|WSS port [HTTPServerHandler class name], got: " + argsString.toString());
        }

        // Configure the server
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        EventLoopGroup worker = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap().group(bossGroup, worker).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

                    if ("wss".equalsIgnoreCase(protocol)) {
                        pipeline.addLast(createSSLContext().newHandler(channel.alloc()));
                    }
                    pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
                    pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(64000));
                    pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/") {
                        @Override
                        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                            super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                            logger.info(String.format("Received frame on channel %s", ctx.channel()));
                        }
                    });
                    pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerHandler());
                    pipeline.addLast(new OutboundLoggingHandler());
                }
            });

            Channel ch = b.bind(port).sync().channel();
            logger.info(String.format("[OK] Server started at %s://%s:%d", protocol, "localhost", port));
            ch.closeFuture().sync();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Exception starting server", e);
        }
        finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            worker.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void addOpenChannel(Channel channel) {
        openChannels.add(channel);
    }

    private static SslContext createSSLContext() throws Exception {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(WebSocketServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/TestKeystore.jks"), "CoraKS".toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, "changeit".toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        return SslContextBuilder.forServer(keyManagerFactory).build();
    }
}

Here is the client code:
public class WebSocketClient {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketClient.class);

    private enum WebSocketProtocol {WS, WSS};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String protocol;
        final String host;
        final int port;
        try {
            protocol = WebSocketProtocol.valueOf(args[0]).toString().toLowerCase();
            host = args[1];
            port = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception parsing main arguments", e);

            StringBuilder argsString = new StringBuilder().append("[");
            for (int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++) {
                argsString.append(args[i]);
                if (i < args.length - 1) {
                    argsString.append(" ");
                }
            }
            argsString.append("]");

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Excepted args: WS|WSS host port, got: " + argsString.toString());
        }

        EventLoopGroup bossLoop = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        try {
            final boolean ssl = "wss".equalsIgnoreCase(protocol);
            final SslContext sslCtx;
            if (ssl) {
                KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                truststore.load(WebSocketClient.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/TestTruststore.jks"), "CoraKS".toCharArray());
                TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                trustManagerFactory.init(truststore);
                sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(trustManagerFactory).build();
            }
            else {
                sslCtx = null;
            }

            // Connect with V13 (RFC 6455 aka HyBi-17). You can change it to V08 or V00.
            // If you change it to V00, ping is not supported and remember to change
            // HttpResponseDecoder to WebSocketHttpResponseDecoder in the pipeline.
            final URI uri = new URI(String.format("%s://%s:%d", protocol, host, port));
            final WebSocketClientHandler webSocketHandler = new WebSocketClientHandler(
                    WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, true, new DefaultHttpHeaders()));

            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(bossLoop)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioSocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(NioSocketChannel ch) {
                    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

                    if (sslCtx != null) {
                        p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
                    }
                    p.addLast(new HttpClientCodec(512, 512, 512));
                    p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(16384));
                    p.addLast(webSocketHandler);
                    p.addLast(new OutboundLoggingHandler());
                }
            });

            logger.info(String.format("Trying to create channel with %s://%s:%d", protocol, uri.getHost(), port));
            final Channel ch = b.connect(uri.getHost(), port).sync().channel();
            webSocketHandler.handshakeFuture().sync();

            logger.info("[OK] Channel created");

            BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while (ch.isActive()) {
                String input = console.readLine();
                if (input == null) {
                    break;
                }

                WsMessage message = null;

                try {
                    if ("ping".equals(input)) {
                        WebSocketFrame frame = new PingWebSocketFrame(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { 8, 1, 8, 1 }));
                        ch.writeAndFlush(frame);
                    }
                    else if ("deconnection".equals(input)) {
                        message = new WsMsgDeconnexion();
                        logger.debug("Sending disconnection message to server...");
                    }
                    else {
                        message = new WsMsgText();
                        ((WsMsgText) message).setText(input);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error during websocket server parsing loop", e.getMessage(), e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (message != null) {
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                    String json = gson.toJson(message);

                    WebSocketFrame frame = new TextWebSocketFrame(json);
                    ch.writeAndFlush(frame);

                    if (message instanceof WsMsgDeconnexion) {
                        logger.debug("Closing channel...");
                        ChannelFuture futureClose = ch.closeFuture().sync();

                        futureClose.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture arg0) throws Exception {
                                logger.debug("[OK] Channel closed");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception starting client", e);
        }
        finally {
            bossLoop.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}

The whole thing is on GitHub here: https://github.com/gaetan-l/websocket
To run the server in WS mode, run WebSocketServer with the following arguments: WS portNo
To run the client in WS mode, run WebSocketClient with the following arguments: WS localhost portNo
You can also use Postman in WS mode, after launching the server, connect to ws://localhost:portNo with Postman, than you can send something like:
{
      "text": "test",
      "type": "com.gaetanl.websocket.message.WsMsgText",
      "creationTime": "Apr 17, 2024 12:18:49 PM"
}

and it should return something.
However if you change WS to WSS in the arguments, you'll see it doesn't work. I can start the server, but not the client (I get an StacklessClosedChannelException). I can see that the server is listening on portNo using netstat though, so I think it launches correctly.
Coincidentally, I have a problem with my Eclipse and I can't use debugging on my Java 1.6 projects (I get an UnsupportedClassVersionError).
Edit: When I try to "ping" my running WSS server using telnet, I can see that the server code is triggered, but not when the Java client is trying to connect.
